# How to crawl RSS feeds or sitemaps of a NEWS WEBSITE using stormcrawler?

Tags: web-crawler, rss, apache-storm, sitemap, stormcrawler

I am using Stormcrawler(v1.16) and Elasticsearch(v7.5.0). I have successfully crawled news websites. BUT when I put rss feeds or sitemaps in seeds.txt it is not crawling.

my seeds.txt is as shown below:

```html
https://www.theguardian.com/world/eu/rss    isFeed=true
https://www.theguardian.com/politics/rss    isFeed=true
https://www.theguardian.com/science/rss isFeed=true
https://www.theguardian.com/education/rss   isFeed=true
https://www.theguardian.com/football/rss    isFeed=true
https://www.elwatannews.com/home/rssfeeds   isFeed=true
```

Topology stats after adding rss feeds to seeds.txt

[[image: topology stat1]

I have also referred to [news-crawl commoncrawler github](https://github.com/commoncrawl/news-crawl) but I have not understood how it is working. What changes should I do so that it can crawl rss feeds and sitemaps also.

Answer (score 0):

The changes you put into the seeds file won't get picked automatically. You need to restart the topology. Once that's done just use Kibana or query ES directly to check the status of your seed URLs and any outlinks they might have picked.

Comment: Hey @julian i have already done that..steps which i have followed are 1st put RSS feeds to seeds.txt and then RUN bash ES_IndexInit.sh and then started topology. Please suggest some thing other than that.

Comment: you seem to have ignored the second part of my suggestions